# Selecting between conversion operators when they are ambiguous

Tags: c++

I have two types:

```
struct A { };
struct B { };
```

And I have functions taking `A` or `B`:

```
void fnA(A); // there are a lot of these functions
void fnB(B);
```

And I have a type, which is convertible to `A` and `B`:

```
struct Foo {
    operator A();
    operator B();
};
```

So I can call `fnA` and `fnB`:

```
fnA(Foo()); // fine
fnB(Foo());
```

Now, I have overloaded function:

```
void fn(A);
void fn(B);
```

I cannot call them with `Foo`, because it is ambiguous:

```
fn(Foo()); // ambiguous, which fn is called
```

I'd like to `fn(A)` be called in this case.

I could add a third `fn` overload:

```
inline void fn(Foo foo) {
    fn(A(foo));
}
```

But I don't like this way, as I have a lot of `fn` functions, and I don't want to increase the number of functions considerably (I have `fn`-like functions scattered all over the place, this change would increase interface size, which is bad for me, as my interface is already huge).

Another solution (which I'll choose if no better alternatives given) is to use inheritance for `Foo`:

```
struct Foo: A {
    operator B();
};
```

In this case, compiler will choose to call `fn(A)` for `fn(Foo())`, it is not ambiguous anymore. But I'm not satisfied with this solution, as `Foo` is not really an `A`, it is a misuse of inheritance (on the other hand, it is a better solution as the previous one, as it solves the problem locally, I don't have to add a lot of unwanted `fn` functions).

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Note: I'd like to have a solution, which doesn't involve explicit conversion, I'd like able to write `fnA(Foo())`, `fnB(Foo())`, and `fn(Foo())`.

Comment: "Is there any other way to solve this problem?" proper way is not to abuse implicit conversion operator

Comment: Maybe explicit keyword may help here

Comment: How about `fn(static_cast<A>(Foo()));`

Comment: Simply tell the compiler explicitly which overloaded operator to call, eg: `fn((A)Foo())` or better `fn(static_cast<A>(Foo()))`

Comment: @Jeka: Unfortunately, the whole point is to have implicit conversion.

Comment: @geza having explicit version with A, compiler will choose non explicit B version

Comment: `Foo` has (implicit) conversions to both `A` and `B` but you always want to pick the overload that takes an `A` ? Or do you sometimes want to pick the `B` overload?

Comment: @user463035818: always `A`.

Comment: @Jeka: the problem is that `fnB(Foo())` won't work anymore implicitly.

Comment: in that case I dont understand why you want to have the conversion to `B` also implicit, anyhow if you want to stay with that you already have an answer

Comment: @user463035818: `fnB(Foo())` should stay OK as well. I'd like to be able to write `fnA(Foo())`, `fnB(Foo())` and `fn(Foo())`, all of them implicit. `fn(Foo())` should call `fn(A)`.

Comment: What purpose does `fn(B)` serve here? It is never called according to your question. Also: Do all your functions have the same signature with only one argument (either `A` or `B`)?

Comment: @MaxLanghof: it is there to make `fn(B())` work.

Comment: @geza "*`Foo` has (implicit) conversions to both `A` and `B` but you always want to pick the overload that takes an A*" - in which case, you probably need to mark the `B` conversion operator as `explicit` (C++11 and later only). Then `fn(Foo())` will always call `fn(A)`. But if you want to call `fn(B)`, or even `fnB()`, then you would have to explicitly cast `Foo` to `B`, eg: `fnB(static_cast<B>(Foo())); ... fn(static_cast<B>(Foo()));` So you have a tradeoff to make.  The compiler can't always do *everything* for you, something you just have to *tell* it what you want.

Comment: @geza Personally, making `Foo` be *implicitly* convertible to *multiple* types seems like a code smell to me. You might need to re-think your design.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Look at Max's answer. With his solution, I don't have to make a tradeoff. I'm not saying that it is a beautiful solution, but does the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can achieve the desired behavior by making each `fn(B)` overload a template:

```
void fn(A);

template<class = void>
void fn(B);

void bar()
{
    fn(Foo());
    fn(A());
    fn(B());
}
```

This causes overload resolution to pick `fn(A)` before considering the templated function. The necessary work amounts to putting `template<class = void>` before every `B` overload of every function (and, if the declaration is separated from the definition, turning all such functions into template specializations).

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E1JgI4).

Comment: Nice, let me check this! (Note, my problem is not with the amount of work, but the amount of functions, and interface size. So if your solution works, then it is absolutely fine by me - I worded my question incorrectly, I'll edit it).

Answer (score 6):

How about a fancy template wrapper:

```
void fn_impl(A);
void fn_impl(B);

template<typename x_AB = A, typename x_Foo = Foo>
void fn(x_Foo && foo)
{
    return fn_impl(static_cast<x_AB>(foo));
}

fn(Foo()); // calls fn_impl(A);
fn<B>(Foo()); // calls fn_impl(B);
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oDXtMk6N1UpjH9C3)

Comment: @NathanOliver I've switched template parameters so now it works. Also foo probably can be an argument with fixed type.

Comment: Looks good now.  It also lets you do `fn({});` and `fn<B>({});` now.

Comment: Is there a way to generalize this (so I don't have to create a template function for each of my `fn`-like functions)? I mean, instead of this solution, I could just easily use the inline function I've put into my answer already. Or is there a difference which makes this solution better?

Comment: Note that you'd also have to explicitly use `fn<B>(B{})` if that were to ever happen. Which (despite not being stated in the question) it probably does, because `fn(B)` likely wasn't written for fun.

Comment: @MaxLanghof One of these calls must be somewhat explicit anyway.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: `fn(Foo())` should call `fn(A)` always. If I want to call `fn(B)` instead, I'll call it with explicit cast, it is no problem. Note, that `fn(B)` exists, because it can be called with `B` as well. I mean, `fn` can be used with `B`, not just with `Foo`.

Comment: @geza Ok, my point was just that `fn(B)` no longer works (and neither does `fn(static_cast<B>(Foo()))`), you need to specify `fn<B>(...)` in either case. That may be acceptable, but as you pointed out, adding an `fn(Foo)` overload would achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just cast `Foo` to the appropriate type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A { };
struct B { };

struct Foo {
    operator A() { return A{}; };
    operator B() { return B{}; };
};

void fn(A) { std::cout << "A"; }
void fn(B) { std::cout << "B"; }

int main()
{
  fn(static_cast<A>(Foo()));
}
```

Comment: @ArnavBorborah the OP doesn't want to as he wants to be able to implicitly cast for other methods.